# dtype changes when using DataFrame.to_dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `uint64` column in my DataFrame, but when I convert that DataFrame to a list of python dict using `DataFrame.to_dict('record')`, what's previously a `uint64` gets magically converted to float:

```py
In [24]: mid['bd_id'].head()
Out[24]:
0                0
1    6957860914294
2    7219009614965
3    7602051814214
4    7916807114255
Name: bd_id, dtype: uint64

In [25]: mid.to_dict('record')[2]['bd_id']
Out[25]: 7219009614965.0

In [26]: bd = mid['bd_id']

In [27]: bd.head().to_dict()
Out[27]: {0: 0, 1: 6957860914294, 2: 7219009614965, 3: 7602051814214, 4: 7916807114255}
```

How can I avoid this strange behavior?

## update

strangely enough, if I use `to_dict()` instead of `to_dict('records')`, the `bd_id` column will be of type int:

```py
In [43]: mid.to_dict()['bd_id']
Out[43]:
{0: 0,
 1: 6957860914294,
 2: 7219009614965,
...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because another column has a float in it. More specifically `to_dict('records')` is implemented using the `values` attribute of the data frame rather than the columns itself, and this implements "implicit upcasting", in your case converting uint64 to float.

If you want to get around this bug, you could explicitly cast your dataframe to the `object` datatype:

```
df.astype(object).to_dict('record')[2]['bd_id']
Out[96]: 7602051814214
```

By the way, if you are using IPython and you want to see how a function is implemented in a  library you can brink it up by putting `??` at the end of the method call. For `pd.DataFrame.to_dict??` we see

```
    ...
    elif orient.lower().startswith('r'):
        return [dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(self.columns, row))
                for row in self.values]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
from pandas.io.json import dumps
import json
output=json.loads(dumps(mid,double_precision=0))
```