# Dtype changes when converting from dataframe to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I read in a csv file from Excel using Pandas, and made it into a dataframe (with many more values, obviously):

```
df_c = pd.read_csv(r'<filename>, low_memory = False)

CRASH_ID    SER_NO  CMPSS_DIR_CD    URB_AREA_CD  CRASH_DAY_NO
1486150     1       2               67           1
1486152     3       7               67           1
1486224     4       2               53           5
1486225     5       9               54           2
```

I converted it to a dictionary using `to_dict`, so that each column name had a list of values associated with it:

```
dfdict = df_c.to_dict(orient='list')
```

But most, if not all of, the numeric values in `dfdict` have been converted to floats for some reason, for some reason:

```
{'CRASH_ID': [1486150, 1486152, 1486224, 1486225],
'SER_NO': [1, 3, 4, 5],
'CMPSS_DIR_CD': [2.0, 7.0, 2.0, 9.0],
'URB_AREA_CD': [67.0, 67.0, 53.0, 54.0],
'CRASH_DAY_NO': [1, 1, 5, 2]}
```

Which is not good, because I need to match the values in `dfdict` with a different list of values, so if some values in `dfdict` have decimals, for example, the matching won't work correctly.

I've checked to make sure the original dataframe doesn't have any floats anywhere in it. It doesn't. I've tried forcing the dataframe to become a string with `df_c.applymap(str)` but the data doesn't change at all, and neither does it change when I try to force the dictionary to contain strings with `df_c.astype(object).to_dict` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374928/dtype-changes-when-using-dataframe-to-dict)).

Comment: which version of pandas do you use ?

Comment: I use version 0.16.2.

Comment: Are there some missing values? i.e. NaNs

Comment: (Pragmatic answer: in python 1 == 1.0, so why not just check for equality.)

Comment: Yes, quite a few NaNs. Are they what's causing the conversion to floats?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by check for equality? You mean when converting to a dictionary? Or later on when I'm matching the values?

Comment: Edit: I filled the NaN values in my dataframe with an empty string with df_c.fillna('', inplace=True). Success! Thanks very much for your help!